3D Canvas Rendering Issue on Mobile Devices
I developed my website using Recat .js, @react-three/fiber
And the 3d drawing is displayed on my laptop
But when I open the website on the mobile, a white screen appears. I don't know what the problem is
Knowing that I tried through my laptop to convert the screen size to a mobile screen through inspect and it worked
I want to know what is the reason behind this problem
my website is https://abdalla-amr.web.app/

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
